# Сделать 302 редирект на указанные ссылки

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Нужно сделать редерект по указным ссылкам. 
Я это делаю таким образом `rewrite ^url$ url redirect;`
и все нормально работает в большинстве случаев.
Но есть ссылки типа таких:

```
https://www.xxx.dev/darla-metallic-heel-ankle-boots-in-grey-faux-suedehttp://www.xxx.com/darla-metallic-heel-ankle-boots-in-grey-faux-suede
https://www.xxx.dev/{{customVar%20code=base_url}}long-boots/lace-up-boots
https://www.xxx.dev/cc-clarke-eclipse-lace-up-over-the-knee-boots-in-faux-snake/{{customVar%20code=base_url}}long-boots/lace-up-boots
https://www.xxx.dev/blog/jeans-and-heels-style-inspo/%5D
https://www.xxx.dev/{{customVar%20code=base_url}}flats/trainers
https://www.xxx.dev/{{customVar%20code=base_url}}flats/flatforms
https://www.xxx.dev/heels/{{customVa%20code=base_url}}heels/party-heels
https://www.xxx.dev/planet-pd/floralhttps://www.xxx.com/
https://www.xxx.dev/trends/style-prom/{{customVar%200code=base_url}}planet-pd/velvet-shoes
```

С ними такое не работает. Я так понимаю что из за {{. Как можно реализовать редирект таких ссылок. Во всех ссылках элементы экранированы.

**config nginx:**

```
## Maps config file
    include conf_m1/maps.conf;

server {
    listen 80 reuseport;
    #listen 443 http2 ssl reuseport;
    server_name www.xxxx.dev localhost;
    root /code/http;

    # limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1000r/s;

    if ($bad_client) { return 444; }

     listen 443 ssl;
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    ## phpMyAdmin config
    ##   include conf_m1/phpmyadmin.conf;

    ## SSL CONFIGURATION
      #ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
      #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    location = /js/index.php/x.js {
       rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
       }

    ## Main Magento @location
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
       }

    ## Server maintenance block.
       #include conf_m1/maintenance.conf;
    ## Error log/page
       #include conf_m1/error_page.conf;

    ## Export folder
       include conf_m1/export.conf;

    ## These locations are protected
    location ~ /(app|var|downloader|includes|pkginfo)/ {
       deny all;
       }

    ## Extra protection and limits
       include conf_m1/extra_protect.conf;
       include conf_m1/redirect.conf;

    ## Images
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
       expires max;
       log_not_found off;
       access_log off;
       add_header ETag "";
       }

    ## Fonts
    location ~* \.(swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    add_header ETag "";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "www.example.com, cdn.example.com";
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location @rewrite {
       rewrite / /index.php;
       }

    ## Execute PHP scripts
    location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       include conf_m1/php_backend.conf;
       ## Store code with multi domain
       #fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $mage_code;
       #fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE $mage_type;
       }
    }
```

Другой файл

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

## Load Dynamic Modules ##
#load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  2048;
    multi_accept on;
       }

http   {
    index         index.html index.php;
    include       mime.types;
    types { application/font-woff2  woff2; }
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" - $request_id';
  # log_format  error403  '$remote_addr - [$time_local] "$request" "$http_user_agent" - $request_id';

    ## Nginx amplify metrics
#    log_format  main_ext '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                         '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                         '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
#                         '"$host" sn="$server_name" '
#                         'rt=$request_time '
#                         'ua="$upstream_addr" us="$upstream_status" '
#                         'ut="$upstream_response_time" ul="$upstream_response_length" '
#                         'cs=$upstream_cache_status' ;

    keepalive_timeout   5;
    autoindex       off;
    server_tokens       off;
    port_in_redirect    off;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    client_max_body_size 64m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_buffer_size 16k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;

    ## Flood protection example (see conf_m2/extra_protect.conf)
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=goeasy:35m rate=1r/s;

    ## Cache open FD
    open_file_cache max=35000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;

    ## Gzipping is an easy way to reduce page weight
    gzip                on;
    gzip_vary           on;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_types          application/javascript application/x-javascript application/rss+xml text/javascript text/css text/plain image/x-icon image/svg+xml;
    gzip_buffers        4 16k;
    gzip_comp_level     6;

    ##  SSL global settings
    #ssl_session_cache      shared:SSL:45m;
    #ssl_session_timeout    15m;
    #ssl_protocols      TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #ssl_ciphers                "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5";
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    #ssl_dhparam        /etc/ssl/certs/dhparams.pem;

    #ssl_stapling on;
    #resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=3600s;
    #resolver_timeout 5s;

    ## Use when Varnish in front
    #set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    #real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

    ## Main domain configuration
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Открываем https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL и узнаем что фигурные скобки **(а также знаки пробелов)** являются зарезервированными символами и их нужно экранировать \{ и \} соответственно. Вперед!

```
https://www.xxx.dev/darla-metallic-heel-ankle-boots-in-grey-faux-suede
http://www.xxx.com/darla-metallic-heel-ankle-boots-in-grey-faux-suede
https://www.xxx.dev/\{\{customVar\ code=base_url\}\}long-boots/lace-up-boots
https://www.xxx.dev/cc-clarke-eclipse-lace-up-over-the-knee-boots-in-faux-snake/\{\{customVar\ code=base_url\}\}long-boots/lace-up-boots
https://www.xxx.dev/blog/jeans-and-heels-style-inspo/
https://www.xxx.dev/\{\{customVar\ code=base_url\}\}flats/trainers
https://www.xxx.dev/\{\{customVar\ code=base_url\}\}flats/flatforms
https://www.xxx.dev/heels/\{\{customVa\ code=base_url\}\}heels/party-heels
https://www.xxx.dev/planet-pd/floralhttps://www.xxx.com/
https://www.xxx.dev/trends/style-prom/\{\{customVar\ 0code=base_url\}\}planet-pd/velvet-shoes
```

Comment: Я это понимаю. И знаю формат их. Дела в том что я их переводил в такой формат и подставлял не сработало

Comment: Обычно я доверяю документации. Но сейчас проверю...

Comment: Может я где ошибся, попробую снова

Comment: Покажите весь конфиг

Comment: Да, действительно. Символы кодируются в браузере таким образом. Но уже nginx получает ракодированную строку запроса и так как эти символы являются зарезервированными уже в самом конфиге nginx, то соответсвенно их нужно предверять знаками обратного слеша - знаком экранирования. Проггеры все должны его знать и использовать. Про сисадминов не знаю

Comment: rewrite ^\/\%7B\%7BcustomVar\%20code\=base\_url\%7D\%7Dflats\/trainers$


{{customVar%20code=base_url}}flats/trainers


Вот такой вариант у меня не работает по какой то из причин

Comment: Кодировать в конфигах nginx не нужно!! я же выше написал

Comment: Если оставить {{customVar%20code=base_url}}flats/trainers тогда появляется токая ошибка nginx: [emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";" in

Comment: вот так работает!!!! **rewrite /\{\{customVar\}\}flats  https://yandex.ru redirect;**

Comment: Да блин почему у меня так не работает. Я сразу все экранирую как писал в посте, не сработало

Comment: **в конфигах nginx не должно быть %7D и т.д. Все зарезервированные символы в nginx просто экранируются и все**

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63402/discussion-between---and-deno).

Comment: Я выложил конфиг, может что там есть из за чего не работает